# I have two CodePens that are identical in HTML and CSS but they have a different output in the browser window

Tags: html, css, forms, codepen

I'm working on creating a survey form  (CodePen A) but I couldn't get the form to display in the centre of the screen. To get focus on the problem I forked the code pen (CodePen B) and removed everything that was not pertinent to the problem. I then started to experiment with the CSS until I (finally) got the form to centre on the screen and was formatted the way I wanted it.

Then, through copy and pasting, I integrated my solution back into the survey form (CodePen A). To to my surprise the survey form did not at all look like what I had created in CodePen B. So I repeated the steps above to fork the survey form into yet another CodePen (CodePen C).  I then tried to recreate my solution in CodePen C.

The HTML and CSS for both CodePen B and C looks identical but their output windows look very different.  I have two questions:

1. What could have gone wrong?
2. How do I fix this?

The two CodePens in questions are:

CodePen B: https://codepen.io/ThomasDirkse/pen/vYZVZeg

```
<html lang="en">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="survey-form">
            <div class="survey-questions">
                <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="input-fields" placeholder="My name" required/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</html>

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.survey-form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #235495;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    background-color: #A6C9E3;
    background-size: contain;
}

.input-fields {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #235495;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

label { 
    color: #235495; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
} 

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

CodePen C: https://codepen.io/ThomasDirkse/pen/eYRPxZR

HTML and CSS for CodePen C is the same as above.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide!  Many thanks in advance.

Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **id** instead of **class** for the value **survey-form**

```
<html lang="en">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <form class="survey-form">
            <div class="survey-questions">
                <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="input-fields" placeholder="My name" required/>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: That's fantastic! I've been banging my head against the glass in the firm belief that both CodePens were in fact identical.  Thank you for spotting the error.  It indeed fixed the problem straight away.